# python filter list of dictionaries based on key value

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and each dictionary has a key of (let's say) 'type' which can have values of `'type1'`, `'type2'`, etc. My goal is to filter out these dictionaries into a list of the same dictionaries but only the ones of a certain "type". I think i'm just really struggling with `list/dictionary` comprehensions.

so an example list would look like:

```
exampleSet = [{'type':'type1'},{'type':'type2'},{'type':'type2'}, {'type':'type3'}]
```

i have a list of key values. lets say for example:

```
keyValList = ['type2','type3']
```

where the expected resulting list would look like:

```
expectedResult = [{'type':'type2'},{'type':'type2'},{'type':'type3'}]
```

I know i could do this with a set of for loops. I know there has to be a simpler way though. i found a lot of different flavors of this question but none that really fit the bill and answered the question. I would post an attempt at the answer... but they weren't that impressive. probably best to leave it open ended. any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You can try a list comp

```
>>> exampleSet = [{'type':'type1'},{'type':'type2'},{'type':'type2'}, {'type':'type3'}]
>>> keyValList = ['type2','type3']
>>> expectedResult = [d for d in exampleSet if d['type'] in keyValList]
>>> expectedResult
[{'type': 'type2'}, {'type': 'type2'}, {'type': 'type3'}]
```

Another way is by using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

```
>>> list(filter(lambda d: d['type'] in keyValList, exampleSet))
[{'type': 'type2'}, {'type': 'type2'}, {'type': 'type3'}]
```

Comment: which is the fastest?

Comment: @DarkSkull I'm not sure about that as I haven't tested it. Feel free to test it and post an answer with your findings. :)

Comment: What if the ```keys``` are different? not just single ```type``` ?

Answer (score 42):

Trying a few answers from this post, I tested the performance of each answer.

As my initial guess, the [list comprehension is way faster](https://towardsdatascience.com/list-comprehensions-vs-for-loops-it-is-not-what-you-think-34071d4d8207), the `filter` and `list` method is second and the `pandas` is third, by far.

> defined variables:

```
import pandas as pd

exampleSet = [{'type': 'type' + str(number)} for number in range(0, 1_000_000)]

keyValList = ['type21', 'type950000']
```

---

---

### 1st - `list comprehension`

```
%%timeit
expectedResult = [d for d in exampleSet if d['type'] in keyValList]
```

> 60.7 ms ± 188 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

### 2nd - `filter` and `list`

```
%%timeit
expectedResult = list(filter(lambda d: d['type'] in keyValList, exampleSet))
```

> 94 ms ± 328 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

### 3rd - `pandas`

```
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame(exampleSet)
expectedResult = df[df['type'].isin(keyValList)].to_dict('records')
```

> 336 ms ± 1.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

---

*On a side note*, using `pandas` to deal with a `dict` is not a great idea since the `pandas.DataFrame` is basically a more memory consuming `dict` and if you are not going to use a dataframe in the end it is just inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for this post ~140ms using filter down to ~30ms using list comprehension!

Comment: Agreed that it's not worth the pandas conversion if you don't need a dataframe but in my testing filtering an existing pandas dataframe is almost identical to using a list comprehension to filter the same data. Your test is recreating the dataframe every time.

Answer (score 19):

Use `filter`, or if the number of dictionaries in `exampleSet` is too high, use `ifilter` of the `itertools` module. It would return an iterator, instead of filling up your system's memory with the entire list at once:

```
from itertools import ifilter
for elem in ifilter(lambda x: x['type'] in keyValList, exampleSet):
    print elem
```

Comment: NOTE: For Python3 the built-in filter() function returns an iterator; itertools.ifilter has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

**Universal approach** to `filter the list of dictionaries based on key-value pairs`

```
def get_dic_filter_func(**kwargs):
    """Func to be used for map/filter function,
    returned func will take dict values from kwargs keys and compare resulted dict with kwargs"""
    def func(dic):
        dic_to_compare = {k: v for k, v in dic.items() if k in kwargs}
        return dic_to_compare == kwargs
    return func


def filter_list_of_dicts(list_of_dicts, **kwargs):
    """Filter list of dicts with key/value pairs
    in result will be added only dicts which has same key/value pairs as in kwargs """
    filter_func = get_dic_filter_func(**kwargs)
    return list(filter(filter_func, list_of_dicts))
```

**Test Case** / How to use

```
    def test_filter_list_of_dicts(self):
        dic1 = {'a': '1', 'b': 2}
        dic2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 3}
        dic3 = {'a': 2, 'b': 3}
        the_list = [dic1, dic2, dic3]

        self.assertEqual([], filter_list_of_dicts(the_list, x=1))
        self.assertEqual([dic1], filter_list_of_dicts(the_list, a='1'))
        self.assertEqual([dic2], filter_list_of_dicts(the_list, a=1))
        self.assertEqual([dic2, dic3], filter_list_of_dicts(the_list, b=3))
```