# Function to filter a list of dictionaries in python based on maximum 4 values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries, and I want to filter the members based on some values, like hostname, idle, ignore, owner and notes.
  This is the format of a member and the list contains more of these:

```
"linux-xxx.subdomain1.subdomain2.subdomain3.domain.com": {
    "cartridge": "xxx",
    "chassis": xx,
    "ignore": "No",
    "ilo": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    "notes": "",
    "owner": "",
    "prefix": "",
    "reason": "",
    "serial": "xxxxxxxxxx"
  }
```

I'm not looking for answers like this: [python filter list of dictionaries based on key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051573/python-filter-list-of-dictionaries-based-on-key-value)

The number of possible filters is high, here is the table.

[image]

My current solution implies the usage of 22 IF's, and I'm not sure if that's a good idea. I'm interested if there is a better method. I'm questioning my method of using lots of IF.