# Accessing list of values from a list of dict for a particular value

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a List of dictionaries that have Names and country and other info, like so:

```
mylist  = [ {'Name': 'Jhon' , 'country': 'usa'},
            {'Name': 'Jhon' , 'country': 'canada'},
            {'Name': 'Mike' , 'country': 'aus'},
            {'Name': 'Mike' , 'country': 'mexico'}]
```

So here if I give "Jhon" as input i want my result to be

```
result = ['usa','canada']
```

I tried

```
result = list(map(lambda x : x['country'], mylist))
```

but this gave me list of all countries for both names how would i get list of country for "Jhon"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/29051573/7954504 and many related answers

Answer (score 0):

Using `map()` you can do like this

```
res = list(map(lambda x: x['country'], filter(lambda x: x['Name'] == key, mylist)))
```

Using list comprehension

```
key = 'Jhon'

res = [d['country'] for d in mylist if d['Name'] == key]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['usa', 'canada']
```

Answer (score 0):

using dict, zip and for loop with condition:

```
mylist  = [ {'Name': 'Jhon' , 'country': 'usa'},
                  {'Name': 'Jhon' , 'country': 'canada'},
                  {'Name': 'Mike' , 'country': 'aus'},
                  {'Name': 'Mike' , 'country': 'mexico'}]
            
IDs = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'] 
            
D = dict(zip(IDs, mylist)) 
            
for k, v in D.items():
    if v['Name'] == 'Jhon':
        print(v['country'])
```

output

```
usa
canada
```

Comment: @deadshot answer is the best one you can find , mine is just another method.