# Filter by list of dictionaries by one key and sort by datetime

Tags: python

I have list of dictionaries like this one

```
actions = [
    {'action':1,'date':datetime(2021, 3, 28, 8, 57, 29, 734261)},
    {'action':2,'date':datetime(2021, 3, 28, 18, 57, 29, 734261)},
    {'action':1,'date':datetime(2021, 3, 29, 20, 57, 29, 734261)}
]
```

And need to first filter them by key value, for instance show only dicts with **action=1**, and then sort them by datetime to show the last one first.

Comment: 28 hour doesn't exists

Comment: Take a look at [python filter list of dictionaries based on key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051573/python-filter-list-of-dictionaries-based-on-key-value/29051598) and [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Comment: Your code doesn't run. you should make sure it runs before posting a question it makes it harder for us to help you...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python filter list of dictionaries based on key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051573/python-filter-list-of-dictionaries-based-on-key-value)

Comment: Where is this question lacking clarity? It is duplicate yes, but not lacking clarity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine

- `filter` with `lambda x: x['action'] == 1` as key
- `sorted` with `lambda x: x['date']` as key and `reversed=True`

```
actions = sorted(filter(lambda x: x['action'] == 1, actions),
                 key=lambda x: x['date'], reverse=True)
```

Comment: That is what I need, thanks