# trying to use getter and setter in a list of dictionaries functions in python but I get the same error

Tags: python, list, dictionary, error-handling

I have a simple program that has to delete some values that are between 2 given "days". For example, I have this list of dicts:

```
lst=[{"day": 1, "sum": 25, "type": 'in'}, {"day": 2, "sum": 55, "type": 'in'}, {"day": 3, "sum": 154, "type": 'out'}, {"day": 4, "sum": 99, "type": 'in'}]
```

and I wanna delete the values with "day" values between 1 and 3 and the output should be:

```
[{"day": 4, "sum": 99, "type": 'in'}]
```

Now I am using this program:

```
def delete_transaction_interval(all_transactions, dayStart, dayEnd):
for element in enumerate(all_transactions):
    if get_transaction_day(all_transactions[element])>=dayStart and get_transaction_day(all_transactions[element])<=dayEnd:
        new_list_transactions=all_transactions[:]
return new_list_transactions
```

but I want to use a getter function instead of `all_transactions[i]["day"]`. I already created the function:

```
def get_transaction_day(all_transactions):
    return all_transactions["day"]
```

but I am using it I got this error:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

and I don't know how to handle it because I do not see any tuple in my code TBH.

My version is:

```
def delete_transaction_interval(all_transactions, dayStart, dayEnd):
    i=0
    while i<=len(all_transactions)-1:
        if get_transaction_day(all_transactions[i])>=dayStart and get_transaction_day(all_transactions[i])<=dayEnd:
            new_transactions_list=all_transactions[:]
        else:
            i+=1
    return new_transactions_list
```

Traceback:

```
    Exception has occurred: TypeError
list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
  File "<String>", line 81, in delete_transaction_interval
    if get_transaction_day(all_transactions[element])>=dayStart and get_transaction_day(all_transactions[element])<=dayEnd:
  File "<String>", line 229, in test_delete_interval
    delete_transaction_interval(all_transactions,1,3)
  File "<String>", line 276, in test_all
    test_delete_interval()
  File "<String>", line 281, in <module>
    test_all()
```

Can somebody help me with this, please?

Comment: Please explain how this question is not the same as your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74295406/exception-has-occurred-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not) one.

Comment: This question is not the same because now I am getting a new error and now I know that is from using getter. If I don't use a getter, the program works well, but I want to use this function and want to learn something and searching on google didn't help .

Comment: The error seems to be the same as the previous one. Please update your question with the full error traceback so we can check.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. A full error traceback should include the source code of each of the lines indicated.

Comment: @quamrana that's all I got when I am running it

Comment: What is your environment?

Comment: @quamrana I run it in debug mode and I got this, I think is right now
VSCode

Comment: But now I see you have modified the error traceback. It is not compatible with the code you have posted: What is: `get_transaction_day(all_transactions[element])`? The code you posted shows: `get_transaction_day(all_transactions[i])`. You are still using your old code from your previous question where `element` was a `tuple`. That's where the error comes from.

Comment: I tried to use a for loop instead. I already edited the question

Comment: So it *is* the same as your deleted question then. Ok, I can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: So, no help? :)) Where is the tuple, and why is that a tuple?

Comment: I just told you: `element` is a `tuple`. It comes from `enumerate()`.

Comment: so, if I change it with  `range` it should work?

Comment: Just look at the answer below or the duplicate of your previous question. Don't use `range()` when you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the list using a forloop if you want to get rid of the index

```
new_transactions_list = []
for elem in lst:
    if not 1 <= elem["day"] <= 3 :
        new_transactions_list.append(elem)
    
print(new_transactions_list)
```

Output

```
[{'day': 4, 'sum': 99, 'type': 'in'}]
```

Comment: I need to use the getter function. Like here: `if get_transaction_day(all_transactions[elem])>=dayStart and get_transaction_day(all_transactions[elem])<=dayEnd:`
That is the main problem I have to solve

Comment: That's just `if get_transaction_day(elem)>=dayStart` etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are desperate to use this function:

```py
def get_transaction_day(all_transactions):
    return all_transactions["day"]
```

I have no problem with that. Small functions are good.

Its just that you must pass something in which works with `["day"]`

Here are some examples:

```py
def delete_transaction_interval(all_transactions, dayStart, dayEnd):
    for element in enumerate(all_transactions):
        if get_transaction_day(element[1])>=dayStart and get_transaction_day(element[1])<=dayEnd:
            new_list_transactions=all_transactions[:]
    return new_list_transactions
```

and from the other answer here:

```py
def delete_transaction_interval(all_transactions, dayStart, dayEnd):
    new_transactions_list = []
    for elem in all_transactions:
        if not dayStart <= get_transaction_day(elem) <= dayEnd:
        new_transactions_list.append(elem)
    return new_transactions
```

or a `range()` version:

```py
def delete_transaction_interval(all_transactions, dayStart, dayEnd):
    for i in range(len(all_transactions)):
        if get_transaction_day(all_transactions[i])>=dayStart and get_transaction_day(all_transactions[i])<=dayEnd:
            new_transactions_list=all_transactions[:]
    return new_transactions_list
```

However, be warned, only one of these will work. The clue is to look in the original duplicate link which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051573/python-filter-list-of-dictionaries-based-on-key-value).