# Python filter specific item using one line of code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

From this code snippet...

```
myItem = {
    'A/A': {'id': 'AA','bool': False},
    'A/B': {'id': 'AB','bool': True},
    'A/C': {'id': 'AC','bool': False},
    'A/D': {'id': 'AC','bool': True}
}
```

how do I filter `myItem` so that I only get those item that has `'bool': True` in it?

I tried doing list comprehension to get `['A/B']` like so:

```
[item for item in myItem if item.endswith('B')]
```

I tried...

```
[item for item in myItem if item.bool==True]
```

but it's giving me an error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'bool'

All I want is to get items `['A/B', 'A/D']` by filtering `'bool': True`, but unfortunately, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: `... if myItem[item]['bool']` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python filter list of dictionaries based on key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051573/python-filter-list-of-dictionaries-based-on-key-value)

Answer (score 1):

You can reconstruct the dictionary object with comprehension, like this

```
myItem = {
    'A/A': {'id': 'AA', 'bool': False},
    'A/B': {'id': 'AB', 'bool': True},
    'A/C': {'id': 'AC', 'bool': False},
    'A/D': {'id': 'AC', 'bool': True}
}

print({key: value for key, value in myItem.items() if value.get('bool', False)})
```

might print

```
{
    'A/B': {'bool': True, 'id': 'AB'},
    'A/D': {'bool': True, 'id': 'AC'}
}
```

The key here is to iterate through all the key-value pairs of `myItem` and filter the items based on the value dictionary's `bool` key.

`if value.get('bool', False)` is to ensure that if `bool` is not found in the dictionary, we ignore that. So, if `bool` is not present, then by default `False` would be returned.

Comment: You don't need to specify a default for `.get` because `None` is falsey

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to filter only items meeting a specific condition and then create a new dictionary out of them (or a list if you prefer):

```py
dict(filter(lambda x: x[1].get('bool'), myItem.items()))
```

This is the result:

```bash
{'A/B': {'id': 'AB', 'bool': True}, 'A/D': {'id': 'AC', 'bool': True}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead:

```
 # Given list 
 myItem = {
'A/A': {'id': 'AA','bool': False},
'A/B': {'id': 'AB','bool': True},
'A/C': {'id': 'AC','bool': False},
'A/D': {'id': 'AC','bool': True}
}
# To filter the keys by bool = True
# for item in myItem : 
#  if myItem[item]['bool']==True:
#     print(myItem[item]['bool'])
# writing the same in list comprehension - one liner
new_list=[item for item in myItem if myItem[item]['bool']==True]
```